# C# multi level object and list access

Tags: c#, oop

I have no idea what should this question be titled nor keyword to search.

**Scenario**:
I have a model as below

```
public class Message { public List<Page> Pages { get; set; }
public class Page { public List<Line> Lines { get; set; }
public class Line { public string Text {get; set; }
```

When I wanted to insert a `Line` with `Text = "Test"` at `Page` 1, I would need to do the following.

```
var Message = new Message();
var line = new Line { Text = "Test" };
var page = new Page();
page.Lines.Add(line);
Message.Pages.Add(page);
```

**Question**: are there any easier way to achieve this? Eg.

```
Message.Pages[0].Lines[0].Text = "Test";
```

Thanks.

**Edit**: Assumed all properties are properly instantiated in constructors.

Comment: OP's code will give object reference error as Lines is not instantiated

Comment: Yea I understand that I would need to instantiate, I have constructors to instantiate the List but not visible here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var msg = new Message {
    Pages = new List<Page> {
        new Page {
            Lines = new List<Line> { new Line { Text = "Test" } }
        }
    }
};
```

Note: if the lists are initialized in their respective constructors, you can remove the `new List<>` bits:

```
var msg = new Message {
    Pages = {
        new Page {
            Lines = { new Line { Text = "Test" } }
        }
    }
};
```

You could also add an implicit conversion operator from `string` to `Line`, in which case:

```
var msg = new Message {
    Pages = {
        new Page {
            Lines = { "Test" }
        }
    }
};
```

---

Edit: fully working example, including operator and ctor initialization, and multiple pages (see comments):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Message {
    public List<Page> Pages { get; private set; }
    public Message() { Pages = new List<Page>(); }
}
public class Page {
    public List<Line> Lines { get; private set; }
    public Page() { Lines = new List<Line>(); }
}
public class Line {
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public static implicit operator Line(string value) {
        return new Line { Text = value };
    }
}

static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var msg = new Message {
            Pages = {
                new Page {
                    Lines = { "Test" }
                },
                new Page {
                    Lines = {
                        "On another page",
                        "With two lines"
                    },
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `new List<T>` can be removed?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy "if the lists are initialized in their respective constructors", yes

Comment: Why constructor initialization matters? You are assigning reference to another list object

Comment: @MarcGravell Say, if I wanted to add new Page with a new Line to the same Message, how can I do that?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy not if you remove the `new List<T>` you aren't; collection initializer syntax of the form `Lines = { new Line {...}}` is **just** an `.Add(...)`

Comment: @AlvinThen you just put in a second `new Page {...}`; I will edit to illustrate

Comment: @MarcGravell Er, I meant after running the statement you provided, say in a for loop, I need to add new Page accordingly.

Comment: @AlvinThen then `.Pages.Add(...)` as necessary

Comment: @MarcGravell cool, thanks. I didn't know that collection initializer can be used out of object creation expression

Answer (score 1):

You can create helper methods in your classes, which will provide handy API for building messages and pages. First is Message class - new Add method accepts page to add, and returns message instance. That will allow to use fluent API for adding pages (example at the bottom):

```
public class Message
{
    public Message()
    {
        Pages = new List<Page>();
    }

    public List<Page> Pages { get; private set; }

    public Message Add(Page page)
    {
       Pages.Add(page);
       return this;
    }
}
```

And page class. I added static creation method, which builds page with any number of lines you pass to this method:

```
public class Page 
{
    public Page() 
    {
        Lines = new List<Line>();
    }

    public List<Line> Lines { get; private set; }

    public static Page WithLines(params string[] texts)
    {
        var page = new Page();

        foreach(var text in texts)
           page.Lines.Add(new Line { Text = text });

        return page;
    }
}
```

Then adding page with lines will look like

```
message.Add(Page.WithLines("Text1", "Text2"))
       .Add(Page.WithLines("Text3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What Marc and Sergey said. Also you can consider a simplified builder. I replaced the properties with fields to make the example smaller:

```cs
public class Message { public List<Page> Pages = new List<Page>(); }
public class Page { public List<Line> Lines = new List<Line>(); }
public class Line { public string Text; }
```

Then your builder would look something like this:

```cs
public class Typewriter
{
    Message message = new Message();
    Page currentPage;

    public Typewriter NewPage()
    {
        currentPage = new Page();
        message.Pages.Add(currentPage);
        return this;
    }

    public Typewriter AddLine(string text)
    {
        currentPage.Lines.Add(new Line() { Text = text });
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```cs
var typewriter = new Typewriter();
typewriter.NewPage().AddLine("First line on first page")
    .AddLine("Next line on first page")
    .NewPage().AddLine("Next page etc");
```